# How to disable “Top Hits” in Mail

Tags: mail.app, high-sierra

macOS High Sierra has a new area in Mail called “Top Hits.” How do I disable/remove it?

[image]

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because someone might know how to do this.  As of last month, when I tried to find a way to remove this, consensus was that it couldn't be removed.  I don't think that's changed recently.

Comment: Can you link to that discussion?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8109581?start=0&tstart=0).  This is just one place that I can remember, sorry.

Comment: Same problem. You can complain at https://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html, as suggested by vermagic123 on https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/disable-top-hits-in-mail-app.2073026/

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Top Hits cannot be disabled. However, it should only show up when your search is rather vague (i.e., searching for the word "the" would surely trigger Top Hits). The more specific your search is, the more likely your results will NOT include Top Hits. Be careful, though - sometimes trying to be too specific may yield no results at all! When I search my email, I try to use as few search terms as possible and always include words that are distinct to the content I'm searching for.

I realize this probably isn't the answer you were looking for, but hopefully I've helped you minimize the likelihood of Top Hits showing up when you search your mail.